# SSIS error when executing the package via Control-M or DTExec

Tags: ssis, control-m, dtexec

So I have created an SSIS package that reads file from a remote directory and load everything it reads into a SQL table.

It works fine in my machine even in the test environment but when I deployed it to production environment everything fails.

I already set the DelayValidation to True, already checked the permission as well and it's all set properly (I think).

These are the scenario I did to at least pin point the error.

**LOCAL MACHINE: TestAccount**

• Run the package via SSMS > Integration Services Catalog > Right Click the package then Execute.  Result: **Sucessfull**

**Remote login to Production Server: TestAccount**

• Run the package via command line dtexec. Result: **Fail**

The error is "Specified in the connection is not a valid" & "The filename is a device or contains invalid character"

Almost run out of idea on how to solve this. :(

Comment: Based on some google searches, sounds like a permissions issue. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ssis+Specified+in+the+connection+is+not+a+valid+The+filename+is+a+device+or+contains+invalid+character&*

Comment: are both the servers the same architecture? 32 or 64 bit? 
Control-M does have a Property "Run as User" is that valid for the PROD run?

Comment: Please confirm that operation that is actually failing - that is, which component is throwing this error.  Does the test account actually have permissions in production?  The remote directory is probably a UNC path?  If that's true, make sure you check the share permissions, not the security settings on the folder itself.

Comment: @manderson I thought that's the culprit but turns out not.

Comment: @InusC They both 64bit. Nope, it's not a valid prod run. The security admin created an account that has all the permission needed to execute the package.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz It's on the beginning of the validation phase for the connection string of text file.. I guess so, because the TestAccount was able to execute the package from my local machine but when I tried it in prod using the same account it fails. Share permission is set to all folders and sub folder.

Comment: Are the local execution and prod execution set to use the same configurations for the file path?

Comment: Hi @mark yes, the path is in UNC format and set to use the same configuration..

Comment: Is there a way on my end to verify if all permissions are indeed set properly? The permissions etc. Are controlled by the admin. I have a feeling that this is a permission issue but i need to prove it first